# Keystore issue ---- Android (google play store) ----not accepting the certificate

Tags: android, google-play, keystore, android-keystore

I recently tried to update my app in the google play store using the apk I generated 3 years ago. I have been using the same key store file since 3 years.All of a sudden, it says SHA1 doesn't match.

I am attaching the screenshot for further reference. I checked the SHA1 values for the key store file before uploading it to the store. The values are exactly the same, but when I upload to the store it gives an error.

I have the key store and the password with me safely. I do not want to lose my app history and i want to update my app with same package name and bundleId. Is there any way to achieve this?

[image: android upload failed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en) to the google play console help, complete instructions for creating a new upload key are written towards the end of the page.